# jQuery Select and Drag elements with relative and absolute position

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a select and drag code that works well until in selection is added a position relative div.

Here is the code and you can see a working demo at http://jsbin.com/azeli/2
To see the problem just mouse select **span 1**, **span 2** and the nested **span 4**

```
$(function() {

  var selected = $([]), offset = {top:0, left:0};
  $("#selectable1").selectable();

    $("#selectable1 span.drag").draggable({

        start: function(ev, ui) {

        selected = $(".ui-selected").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.data("offset", el.offset());

        });

        offset = $(this).offset();

      },

      drag: function(ev, ui) {

        var dt = ui.position.top - offset.top, dl = ui.position.left - offset.left;

        selected.not(this).each(function() {
          var el = $(this), off = el.data("offset");
          el.css({top: off.top + dt, left: off.left + dl});
          });

      },  

  });
  });
```

Please let me know if this can be fixed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make the position absolute for all elements within the selection, restore the original position when the selection changes.

outside the loop

```
var originalPositions = new Array();
```

inside the loop

```
// call the restorePositions() that goes through the array of 
// saved elements, restoring each position and remove the element from the array;
// if element in the loop has a position thats not relative, add to array
el.css({position: 'absolute', top: off.top + dt, left: off.left + dl});
```

Comment: I thought of that but if nested span 4 changes from relative to absolute the text breaks as it leaves a gap where the relative position span was.

Comment: for that you need to remove the current left and top, when you mark something as absolute, with no left or top, it remains on the same spot and the text will behave better if you have inner containers that are not draggable and handle this overflow.

Comment: I am new to jQuery and it takes me some time to figure this out. i did not solve this yet but I will let you know how it goes.
Thanx for the advices!

Comment: Sorry, I could not make this work for me. I am still getting the same problems.